# How to create a multi worker coroutine with queue in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, python-asyncio, pysnmp

I'm trying to create a multiworker async coroutine with queue to collect information with PySNMP.
Only Python 3.5 is available. I tried to create my script based on a script in Python 3.7 but as asyncio fundamentaly different in Python 3.5, and have got stuck on this.

I have got error message: `'asyncio' has no attribute 'create_task'`.

Could anyone take a look, what needs to be changed to make this script work.

```
import asyncio, random, time
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio import *


async def worker(queue):
    snmp_engine= SnmpEngine()

    while True:
        next_ip = await queue.get()

        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = await getCmd(SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'),
            UdpTransportTarget((next_ip, 161)), ContextData(), ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0))
        )
        print(errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds)

        queue.task_done()


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    for _ in range(100):
        queue.put_nowait("104.236.166.95")

    tasks = []
    for i in range(3):
        task = asyncio.create_task(worker( queue))
        tasks.append(task)

    started_at = time.monotonic()
    await queue.join()
    total_slept_for = time.monotonic() - started_at

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    print(total_slept_for)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Python 3.7, the `asyncio.ensure_future()` function can be used instead of `asyncio.create_task()`.